# Can you make a layer clickable? Going to a URL?

Tags: css

Can you make a layer clickable, going to a url?

Here's my layer, with a background picture.  I want my users to click it to navigate.

CSS:

```
#content-2-2 
{
    float: left;
    width: 269px;
    height: 103px;
    margin:0px 20px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: url('../images/Guided-tour-logo-front.png') no-repeat left top;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content-2-2"></div>
```

Regards,
Tea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an anchor:

```
<div id="content-2-2"><a href="url here"></a></div>

#content-2-2 
{
    float: left;
    width: 269px;
    height: 103px;
    margin:0px 20px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: url('../images/Guided-tour-logo-front.png') no-repeat left top;
}

#content-2-2 a
{
    width: 269px;
    height: 103px;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't via css...try using something like:

```
<div id="content-2-2" onclick="location.href='http://www.example.com'"></div>
```

It's javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

For example:

```
<div id="facebook" onclick="location.href='your_link.html'">
```

and then in your CSS:

```
    #facebook{
     cursor: pointer; 
     /* The rest of your styling to that div */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 Allows for anchors to wrap block elements. This should work if you are using HTML5:

`<a href="link.html">
 <div id="content-2-2">my content</div>
</a>`